# When I unplugged one of the four 2.5" SSDs, the RAID 5 made by MADAM disappeared

Tags: mdadm, read-only, raid5

I create RAID 5 with 4pcs of SSDs using this command

> [sudo mdadm --create /dev/md5 --level=5 --raid-device=4 /dev/sda
> /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd]

and use

> [lsblk]

to see the RAID5, which is 720GB md5 , is successfully built.

[See 1st Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk6Ss.jpg)

Then I unplug one of the four 2.5" SSDs to test RAID 5 backup mechanism.
And the 720GB md5 (RAID5) disapear.
I try to make a folder in R5 Volume, which is the volume I just built via RAID5, and it shows error message

```
Error creating directory/media/fr/R5/6:Read-only file system.
```

[See 2nd Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KD1A.jpg)

Why 720GB md5 (RAID5) disapear?

Why R5 partition/volume become " Read-only file system " ?

I did the same action ( unplug one of the four 2.5" SSDs ) when I built RAID 1 and RAID 10  respectively, and the result is that each partition/volume exists and I successfully made a folder in each RAID partition/volume.